# Laravel 5.2 + Service Providers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and want to follow best prectices.

Laravel 5.2 comes up with built in service providers.

1. AppServiceProvider.php
2. AuthServiceProvider.php

and likewise.

One use I could find about this files are to define custom Validators in it. Is there any other rule of it?

Why does laravel provide separate files for app and auth out of the box?

Comment: You should look up `SOLID Principle`, and understand Dependency Inversion - this is where Service Providers will be very useful and extremely powerful

Answer (score 0):

Service Providers are not used for validation, the name is self descriptive, they provide any kind of service to your application.

For example you can have a service provider as an Observer for your models, to register all this observers you need a Service Provider.

Comment: This is not quite accurate, Service Providers are a simple but flexible implementation of `Dependency Inversion` a bit like Phalcon Frameworks' Di object, where as this is more extensible *(though it's subjective as to whether Phalcon `Di` is better or not to Laravels' Service Container)*